# MultiSelectionHelper not working as expected

Tags: x++

I'm trying to perform an operation on multiple lines on my form. I have tried to use `multiselectionhelper`, and it seems as it would work, but for some reason, it's not. My operation is still looking at the last line I have selected instead of all the selected lines.

```
myTable myTableTmp;
MultiSelectionHelper selectionHelper = MultiSelectionHelper::construct();

selectionHelper.parmDatasource(myTable_ds);

myTableTmp = selectionHelper.getFirst();
while (myTableTmp )
{
    //perform operation
    myTableTmp = selectionHelper.getNext();
}
```

This looks like it would work, but still not working as expected. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your implementation looks correct so far. Can you tell us more about the context? In which method did you place this code? Are there any special filters or queries used? Maybe you could provide an xpo that shows your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally figured it out. I'm not sure how I missed it. The answer was really simple. I had this:

```
    myTable myTableTmp;
MultiSelectionHelper selectionHelper = MultiSelectionHelper::construct();

selectionHelper.parmDatasource(myTable_ds);

myTableTmp = selectionHelper.getFirst();
while (myTableTmp )
{
    localTable.methodCall();
    myTableTmp = selectionHelper.getNext();
}
```

I should have used `myTableTmp.methodCall()` instead of the `localtable.methodCall()`

Thanks for anyone that tried to help!